# Sum of matrix element in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am NewBie to Rcpp and R. I tried to compute the edge count or the wedge count from a adjacency matrix. For that I write the followin code in Rcpp.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double wedge_cnt_cpp(NumericMatrix x){
  
  size_t  n = x.nrow();
  double temp = 0.0;
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(size_t j=0; j<n; j++){
      for(size_t k=0; k<n; k++)
      temp = temp + x[i][j]*x[j][k];
    }
  }
    return temp;
}
```

This code gives the following error

```
subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
```

I'm unable to detect the error, any kind of help appreciated.

Comment: Check the syntax for matrix subsetting. Also, it seems dangerous to use `int` for the return value. You should use a double variable to avoid overflow.

Comment: @Roland thanks for the suggestion, I edited it.

Comment: Hi @ManAni and welcome to StackOverflow and Rcpp!  You made a somewhat elementary mistake in your code so you may benefit from reading a few Rcpp code examples -- for example in the [RcppExamples package](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=RcppExamples) or at the [RcppGallery site](https://gallery.rcpp.org/).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks for the suggestion, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `x(i,j)` instead of `x[i][j]`, and return `double` type `temp` to play it say if your input is double. For example

```
library(Rcpp)

sourceCpp(
    code = "
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double wedge_cnt_cpp(NumericMatrix x){

  size_t  n = x.nrow();
  double temp = 0;

  for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(size_t j=0; j<n; j++){
      for(size_t k=0; k<n; k++)
      temp = temp + x(i, j) * x(j,k);
    }
  }
    return temp;
}"
)
```

and you will see

```
> set.seed(0)

> (A <- matrix(sample.int(4), 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    1    3

> (B <- matrix(runif(4), 2))
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.9082078 0.8983897
[2,] 0.2016819 0.9446753

> wedge_cnt_cpp(A)
[1] 46

> wedge_cnt_cpp(B)
[1] 4.117935
```

Comment: Better use `R_xlen_t` instead of `size_t`.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for sharing the knowledge, now I learnt it. BTW, why `R_xlen_t` is better? Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Roland Just out of curiosity.... is there any specific reason for using `R_xlen_t`?

Comment: @ManAni https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Long-vectors